# Fastly CDN - do not cache specific sections of a page

Tags: iis, cdn, varnish-vcl, fastly

I am reading Fastly's guides on how to cache pages or using conditions to not cache specific pages. The site I'm working on has some dynamic elements present on all pages of the site which I need to not be cached.

The Fastly guides mention passing specific HTTP headers or using conditions to cache pages and this makes sense for full pages. However, I can't find a clear answer on how to tell the system to not cache **parts** of a given page while still caching the rest of the page.

Anyone got an example of how I would do this, ideally using IIS / C#?

Comment: Do you have any links towards the fastly guide section describing how to cache page?

Comment: I've since figured out that this needs to use Edge Side Includes....currently trying to figure out how to get these working in MVC though is a different thing....